# Proof that every conformal function $(f'\ne 0)$ is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

> If $U$ is an open subset of the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, then a function $f:U\to \mathbb{C}$  is conformal *if and only if* it is holomorphic and its derivative is everywhere non-zero on $U$.

How would you prove this? In the literature, I was only able to find the proof of

> If $U$ is an open subset of the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, then a function $f:U\to \mathbb{C}$  is conformal *if* it is holomorphic and its derivative is everywhere non-zero on $U$.

Any references are appreciated.

Comment: What's your definition of conformal? Because depending on the definition, you can just read the Cauchy-Riemann equations out of the differential of $f$.

Comment: See p.126 in Gamelin’s Complex Analysis.

Comment: I guess the way you used to define a conformal map is something along the line of angle-preserving? Then usually we give the angle at $\gamma(0)$ as $\arg \gamma'(0).$ This notion is usually only defined when $\gamma'(0)\not =0.$

Comment: @JustWandering Exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you wanted to show that $T$ is conformal $\Longrightarrow$ $T$ is holomorphic and has non-vanishing derivative. I can think of if it is holomorphic then it cannot have vanishing derivative.

Suppose $T:U\to\mathbb{C}$ is conformal. Take any $u,v\in U,$ take a path $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $\gamma(0)=u,\gamma(1)=v$ such that the angle of $\gamma$ is defined at $u$, that is $\gamma'(0)\not =0.$ Since $T$ is conformal, we must have $(T \circ\gamma)'(0)\not =0.$ Then by chain rule, we have $T'(u)\gamma'(0)\not=0.$ Since $u$ is arbitrary and that $T$ is holomorphic on $U$ and the derivative must not vanish.

However though, if you want to show $T$ is holomorphic I think you need extra conditions such as $T$ is continuously real-differentiable and its total derivative is also non-vanishing.

I guess the moral here is that it is really depending on the way of defining a conformal map, if you just say it is angle preserving then there is nothing stopping you from being a not holomorphic function.

Comment: You don't need extra conditions to show that $T$ is holomorphic. Any reasonable definition of conformality will either include or imply real-differentiability. And then conformality will imply that the differential of $T$ is conformal, which is equivalent to complex differentiability of $T$ due to the Cauchy-Riemann equations. So if $T$ is conformal everywhere, then it is complex differentiable everywhere, and thus holomorphic.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos A function $f:U\to V$ is called conformal (or angle-preserving) at a point $u_{0}\in U$ if and only if it preserves angles between directed curves through $u_{0}$, as well as preserving orientation (where $U$ and $V$ are open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$). How does that imply real differentiability?

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Yes that is correct, usually real-differentiability is included as a part of definition. However, would you mind if you put down more detail in this post as an answer on why the differential of T is conformal and why does it therefore imply it is holomorphic please? I am interested in seeing how that argument works as well!

Comment: I think I was a bit overzealous. I tried actually writing down a proof of real differentiability from just angle and orientation preservation, but I couldn't manage. I also couldn't find a counterexample, though. So maybe differentiability needs to be assumed as an extra condition. But continuous differentiability doesn't. Differentiability of a conformal map alone will imply complex differentiability due to the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Complex differentiability on open sets is holomorphy, which is known to then imply continuous differentiability.

Comment: @JustWandering Why you have taken $(T \circ \gamma)'(0) \neq 0$? How conformality of $T$ gives that condition in the image curve?